# Tensorflow FailedPreconditionError Could not find variable training_28/Adam/learning_rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to train a model but I'm getting this error:

```
FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Failed precondition: Could not find variable training_28/Adam/learning_rate. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status=Not found: Resource localhost/training_28/Adam/learning_rate/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node training_28/Adam/Identity/ReadVariableOp}}]]
     [[loss_1016/AddN_1/_4689]]
```

My model:

```
optim = Adam(learning_rate=0.0005,beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)

# create NN for news clissification:
news_DNN = Sequential()
news_DNN.add(Dense(40, input_dim=768, activation = 'relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1)))
news_DNN.add(Dropout(0.25))
news_DNN.add(Dense(40, activation = 'relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1)))
news_DNN.add(Dropout(0.25))


# Output layer with multiclass activation function:
news_DNN.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

# Compile model:
news_DNN.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim, metrics=['acc'])

m_h = news_DNN.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=400, \
validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=32, verbose=0)
```

X_train and test Y_train and test are of type

```
[[ 0.28848816 -0.16448754  0.64873524 ...  0.27310849 -0.12281874
  -0.2944856 ]
 [ 0.28848816 -0.16448754  0.64873524 ...  0.27310849 -0.12281874
  -0.2944856 ]
 ...]
```

I don't understand this error at all. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: what's your `tf` versoin? Can you provide some reproducible code (with some dummy data)?

Comment: I am using tf v1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using disable_eager_execution by any chance? I was getting a similar problem and deactivating this option solved it for me! Hope this helps.